# generic makefile?

Tags: windows, makefile

Is there a generic makefile i can use to build a simple c++ project? on windows?
i modified a working wii makefile to win32 but could not build properly (difference in make? the make app and the makefile seem to be found). I did a little hack and made a copy of mingw32-make as make.

-edit-
export PATH seem to be the reason i got my old error (make: make Command not found)
now using my new makefile (single file instead of 2) i get

> "make" 
>   make[1]: Nothing to be done for `/c/nightly/test/test.exe'.

this is my current makefile
http://pastie.org/318548

I am using mingw. I have a installation from that site along with another with codeblocks. the 'make' binary is a copied mingw32-make.exe where i chopped off the prefix. doing make -h i get "This program built for i686-pc-msys" so it looks correct

Answer (score 1):

Your make file looks fine, for the most part.

Check to see that gcc and g++ are installed correctly.

Also the Clean target uses: rm -rf

rm is the unix (linux et al) command for remove. In order to get rm on windows, I recommend using Cygwin.

Which C++ compiler are you using?

Comment: i tried changing rm to del, the command was not found.

i am using mingw current (not candidate) release and i have another copy installed with codeblocks. I updated my post for more info.

Answer (score 0):

As indicated in the error message, the problem does not come from your Makefile.

"make" itself couldn't be found in your path.